# Magento: Using Custom layout update XML to remove price

Tags: magento

In Magento i want to remove the prices from all articles in certain categories by using a custom layout update in the category.

This is what i came up with my self, but i'm still missing the last piece of the puzzle.

```
<catalog_product_view>
    <reference name="product_list">
       <remove name="xxx" />
    </reference>
</catalog_product_view>
```

In the above piece of code i need the corresponding name for the price template.
Does anyone know which one i have to use here?

Thanks!!